# Model of complete extension of Zermelo set theory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Chang and Keisler's Model theory gives the following exercise problem:

> Prove that there is a complete extension $T$ of [Zermelo set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) which has arbitrary large natural models.
>
> (A model $\mathfrak{A}$ of set theory is *natural* if $\mathfrak{A}=(V_\alpha,\in)$ for some $\alpha$. )

I don't know how to prove this problem. Any hints or ideas will be very appreciated.

Comment: There is a proper class of $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ is a model of Zermelo, but there are only set many completions, and each of these $V_\alpha$ satisfies one of them. (It is just the pigeonhole principle: If class many pigeons go into set many pigeonholes, one of the pigeonholes ends up with class many pigeons inside.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I took my answer below to be a more explicit version of this argument. Was it not clear enough? (Genuine question).

Comment: @GME Your answer seems clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it. Suppose it fails. Then let $F(T)$ be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that for all $\beta>\alpha$, $V_\beta\not\vDash T$ (where $T$ is a complete extension of $Z$). Since the complete extensions of $Z$ form a set, Replacement implies that $rng(F)$ is a set and thus that it has a least upper bound $\beta$. Let $\lambda$ be the least limit greater than $\beta$. Then $V_\lambda\not\vDash T$ for all complete extensions $T$ of $Z$, which is impossible.